# Pasar String de Ids numéricos como parámetro sqlcommand en sentencia WHERE IN

Tags: sql, string, update

no consigo pasar la cadena p_strValores con valores:

> 2844099,2844100,2844101,2844102,2844103,2844104,2844105,2844106,2844107,2844108,2844109,2844110,2844111,2844112,2844113,2844114,2844115,2844116,2844117,2844118

con

```
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p_Ids", p_strValores));
```

a la sentencia

```
UPDATE tbl_Datos 
SET col_Leyenda = (select col_Id from tbl_Leyenda where col_Leyenda = @p_Leyenda) 
WHERE col_Id in (@p_Ids)
```

dice no se puede convertir nvarchar a int, como se podria pasar al IN(...IDs...) 
?

Gracias

Comment: Seguramente estás llamando a un SP, dónde tienes definido `@p_Ids` como INT, podrías hacer que sea una cadena, pero ya no te serviría el `IN` deberías hacer otra cosa. Creo que tu pregunta, en realidad debería ser: ¿Cómo pasar un conjunto de valores posibles por parámetro para ser usados en un determinado filtro?. Te sugiero que agregues el código del SP a la misma. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero pasas tu cadena a `List`

```
List<string> p_Ids= p_strValores.Split(',').ToList();
```

luego convertir cada valor a int en de la lista `p_Ids`, con un `for` y agregarlos una lista auxiliar supongamos `ax_p_Ids` con la cual

```
UPDATE tbl_Datos SET col_Leyenda = (select col_Id from tbl_Leyenda where col_Leyenda = @p_Leyenda) WHERE col_Id in ax_p_Ids
```

Comment: Lo intente y me sigue poniendo lo mismo , incluso puse las comillas simples y sigue diciendo que no puede convertir de nvarchar a int. No lo entiendo, al final lo hice con string.format  pasando la cadena en un {0}

Comment: Vale si que funciona , con lista de ints , gracias!